# Google App Indexing iOS SDK CocoaPods alternative

Tags: cocoapods, google-search-platform

Is there an alternative way of obtaining the iOS SDK for Google App Indexing or do I have to use CocoaPods?

i.e. are the required files available as a standalone download that I can pull into my app as a once-off operation without having to get them via CocoaPods?

Reason I ask is that I'm operating in a restricted environment where any change to our project structure caused by integrating with CocoaPods (i.e. creation of .xcworkspace file) will impact our build process and also our firewall will give us problems when attempting to install the pod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question - but...

You can always find the source file locations for a cocoapod by looking it the `Podspec` file for that pod. For Google App Indexing it is available [here for the 2.0.2 release](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleAppIndexing/2.0.2/GoogleAppIndexing.podspec.json). As you can see the files are available at https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/f4087bb21bf46c7e-GoogleAppIndexing-2.0.2.tar.gz.

Unzipping that tar and you have a framework and bundle that will need to be included in your project. For the sake of completeness in this answer - dependency management, etc etc etc. If cocoa pods is something that you can't use take a look at https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage.